# Is there a textual representation of SQLServer Error Severity Level?

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for a textual representation for severity levels reported by SQLServer error messages.  I found a mapping for the error number (*message_id*):

```
   SELECT message_id, severity, text FROM sys.messages WHERE message_id = 1205
```

Does something comparable exist for the severity level code or is there some list available that names each severity code?  All I found was this categorizing stuff on MSDN that tells me that all codes below 10 are informational etc...

Comment: The best information I have seen on this is in the article by Erland Sommarskog [Error Handling in SQL 2000](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#severitylevels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most comprehensive list I have seen is this MSDN article [Database Engine Severity Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx)

Although, for severity levels =< 10 it isn't specific but as these informational I don't see this as too much of a issue?  The Database engine doesn't even raise these as errors.

Comment: +1 That is more comprehensive (and presumably up-to-date) than my link. Erland's article is still worth a read though.

Comment: @Martin: I agree, IMO anything that Erland writes about SQL Server is worth a read.